# from object in Tuple[of Sets()]: - is giving me the whole Tuple back instead of just one Set

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, python-2.7, pygame

I'm starting to write an AI for a uni portfolio in Python.

The AI is for a game called Planet Wars, which is a clone of GalCon (Galactic Confusion).

It's in it's basic stage thus far. My goal is to write an AI which loosely follows Sun Tzu's the Art of War, as I interpret it for the game.

I'm kludging through, learning as I go, but for the life of me I can't figure out why line 92 gives me the whole of self._currentTactics instead of just one tactic at a time...

I'd love it if the lovely people around here could help me out.

Just the AI File:

http://pastebin.com/XXYiRzh7

The whole game's code(requires pygame):

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mma5qwd2iv0i81d/mpemB7zlhT

Comment: Just as a note this is a terrible question. You were lucky someone answered, in future, you should distil your problem down to a specific, reasonably-sized bit of code, and post that code up here, not by linking to it.

Comment: What is your question exactly? That's very confusing, it **sounds** interesting, but in that state I am unable to answer your question.

Comment: @Lattyware Thanks for the response, I'll do my best to improve my questions in the future.
I've just posted a new question, hopefully it's more concise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like `_compare` is appending a list of tactics to `_currentTactics`, which would then cause a loop iterating over `_currenTactics` to return the entire list of tactics rather than one at a time.  I think you might be looking for `self._currentTactics += new_tactics` instead, as this will merge the lists together.

Comment: Trying

        for tactic in new_tactics:
            self._currentTactics.append(tactic)

I'll let you know

Comment: I'd also recommend you look in to the data structures you are using.  You seem to be referring to lists as tuples and tuples/dicts as sets.

Comment: Yeah, I should look into that. I always get confused about their names. I just remember () is immutable and unique whereas [] is unordered, mutable.
{k:v} is a dict. That's the only one I always remember.

Comment: `[]`(lists) are ordered and mutable.  Only an explicitly created `set()` and a dict are unordered.  A `(1,2)` tuple is both ordered and immutable.